# Difference between functions filter() and arima.sim()

Tags: r, time-series, simulation

I want to simulate this AR process $$X_t=0.7X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$$

What is the difference between functions `filter()` and `arima.sim()`?

For example this code:

```
set.seed(154)
w = rnorm(500,0,1)
x=filter(w, filter=c(.7), method="recursive")
```

and this code

```
set.seed(154)
xarima=arima.sim(n=500, list(ar=c(0.7)), sd=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

When describing an AR process, many authors only describe the conditional distribution (with a recursion, like you have), and omit the description of the distribution of $X_0$. This can lead to significant confusion. In particular, the AR process you've described may or may not be stationary, depending on the initial distribution.

For example, if $X_0 \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}\right)$ (the *stationary distribution* for the process), then the conditional distribution $X_t|X_{t-1} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\phi X_{t-1},\sigma^2\right)$ implies that $X_t \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}\right)$ as well, for all $t$, and the process is stationary.

However, if the initial distribution is degenerate such that $X_0 = 0$, then the process is *not* stationary. You can compute that:

$$\text{Var}(X_1) = \sigma^2$$
$$\text{Var}(X_2) = (1+\phi^2)\sigma^2$$
$$\text{Var}(X_3) = (1+\phi^2+\phi^4)\sigma^2$$

You can see that, if $|\phi| < 1$, then as $t$ grows, $\text{Var}(X_t)$ tends to $\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}$. Indeed, the process still converges in distribution to the stationary distribution $\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}\right)$, but if you are simulating this process for a finite number of periods, then the first few iterates will not follow the stationary distribution. If you actually really do want to simulate from the stationary distribution, then a common strategy to avoid this is to simulate for $N$ more points than you need, and discard the first $N$ points (the "burn-in" period).

Implicitly, by default, both `stats::filter` and `stats::arima.sim` proceed as if the degenerate $X_0 = 0$ initial condition was used. However, `stats::arima.sim` automatically computes an appropriate burn-in period length before simulating and discarding it (for $\phi=0.7$, in `stats` version 3.6.3, it's 18 periods). `stats::filter` just starts from zero without doing anything special, which means that it will not return the same result, even for the same RNG seed.

This part of the answer is not really on topic here, but in case you have noticed that, given the same seed, the result of `arima.sim` is identical to `filter` but shifted in time, the reason is not a statistical issue. It's because the burn-in innovations are generated before the rest of the innovations (so the process starts from the same seed), even though they appear later in the arguments of the function. This has to do with how lazy evaluation works in R and could change in a later version.